# Subtract dates within CASE expression

Tags: postgresql, datediff

I am looking to find out how many days are between 2 dates in a query.  This is probably something simple to a seasoned Postgres person, but I cannot find an answer..

And help would be great.

```
CASE
 WHEN DATEDIFF('day',a.date_approve,a.current_rec_date) = 1 
     THEN a.current_rec_date
 ELSE a.date_approved
END AS date_approved,
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `datediff()` in Postgres.

If the columns are `date`s then simply subtracting them will give you the difference in days.

```
...
a.date_approve - a.current_rec_date = 1
...
```

If they're `timestamp`s subtracting them will get you an `interval` so you'd need to compare it to an `interval`.

```
...
a.date_approve - a.current_rec_date = '1 day'::interval
...
```

You can get more information from the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-datetime.html).

Comment: Hmmm....I run a query like:  SELECT date_approved - current_rec_date = '1 day'::interval FROM approved_recommendations WHERE label= 'EVA';   And I get a result of 'true'.

Comment: @LandonStatis: So `date_approved` and `current_rec_date` are one day apart. Aren't they?